# What is Facebook developer hash key and why is it needed?

Tags: android, facebook

In order to integrate an Android application with Facebook, it is required to generate a key hash.

Here the question is not how to generate it but, rather, why is that needed. Facebook explains that it needs Android key hash to ensure the authenticity between Facebook and the application. However, it is unclear to me why does Facebook need a unique key hash for the development environment?

And, what if there are multiple developers for the application, each with their own development environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common practice and is used to protect against abuse of an API key even if it is being used in a development environment. The API key is something that can be fairly easily extracted from an APK, and the SDK API can authenticate the app based on its signing key.

It is recommended that you share your development signing key for an application with all the developers working on the app. This can easily be done by checking in the signing key along with your project. The signing key that Android Studio creates for you is located in `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`. You can copy this key (or create a new one) into your project and include it in your `build.gradle` config file. eg:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../keystores/debug.keystore")
        }
        release {
          :
        }
}
```

This solves your issue of using the same facebook key for everyone in the development environment. Additionally, it allows anyone in the development team to build and distribute a debug version of the app that will always be signed with the same key.